# Checking if a p=0.5 coin is fair (or maybe simply alternating states)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**Background**

In a psychological experiment we have conducted participants need to make judgements be pressing one of two buttons for every trial.

We would like to identify participants who are not paying attention and are just clicking.

The conditions of the task are pseudo-randomized such that an engaged participant will use either button roughly 50% of the time in a pseudo-random distribution.

Some participants, however, still get that 50% expected rate, by using a clicking strategy (say by alternating buttons every trial).

**The Question**
Given a list of button presses (or coin flips for that matter) we would like to figure out which distributions are structured and which are "random".

For instance, in the following distribution the probability of getting an heads is 50%. However, as you can see, all of these coins are NOT fair, but patterned.

[image]

What can we do to measure or random is the distribution of the coin flips?

**Hint?**
My mind immediately goes to some sliding window where I check the rate of each condition at each window. But, such a strategy would fail to identify situation B.
I'd love to get advice.

Thanks!

Comment: In a run of say $1000$, you would expect a certain number of each run-length (I haven't worked out the exact ratios yet!).

Comment: Be warned that you'll hit false-positives in the event that the coin truly was fair but *just so happened to randomly* coincide with one of these presumed unfair patterns.

Comment: You should check run distributions, that is the name. For instance, there is a distribution for the number of runs, and also a distribution for the size of these runs. A computer will help and give you an idea how unlikely this patterns are. For example, in all these examples, there is only 2 ways to get as many runs of the given size (start with black or with white).

Comment: The run-distributions are only needed to check the independence of the throws. If we assume independence (and this is usually done) , you only need a simple hypothesis test for the probability to throw "heads".

Comment: The Kolmogorov complexity is very useful to measure the randomness of a binary sequence, unfortunately it is uncomputable.

Comment: @Peter, how is it useful if it's not computable?

Comment: Ended up using the Runs Distribution Test

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to look at conditional probabilities. A truly fair coin should have flips that are independent of one another - no matter what the prior flips were, the chance of heads is 50%. You could check to see that the probability of heads is 50% even when conditioned on prior flips. Basically, what is the chance of getting heads given that the *previous* flip was heads?

In Case A, you'll see that the chance of getting heads given that the last flip was heads is far higher than 50%, and in Case B, you'll see that the chance of getting heads given that the last flip was heads is far lower than 50%. These conditional probabilities indicate that the coin has some "memory" and that the flips are not independent of one another. Conditioning on longer runs can help you explore this deeper, allowing you to find unexpected patterns if the last *two* flips were heads (Case C), or if the last *three* flips were heads (Case D).

Comment: How would you measure that? Using sliding windows?

Comment: @MichaelSeltenreich You could generate a 2x2 contingency table that counts co-occurrence of a trial being heads and a trial being preceded by heads, and run a chi-square or Fisher test on it. If you see significant association between the outcome of the current trial and the outcome of the last trial, it's strong evidence that the outcomes are not independent - people are picking outcomes with respect to whatever they picked last.